# How to avoid js tag merging (from addJs) in magento?

Tags: layout, javascript

I discovered that Magento - when calling the addJs php function and when using the layout.xml file - merges all the javascript  tag in one single tag, producing something like

```
<script src="domain.com/js/scriptA.js,/js/scriptB.js,/js/scriptC.js"> etc...
```

How can I disable this (awful) feature?

Answer (score 1):

Log in to your admin and go to System --> Configuration.  Select Developer from the left sidebar and disable JavaScript merging.

Comment: tried it, but it still combines js calls in one tag...

Comment: Did you clear your cache after changing that setting?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is disabling js merging on system>configuration>developer, or (in my case) disable extensions like "fooman speedster". Banged my head for a solid afternoon.